# Android Application - Credentials in RAM

Tags: android, memory, credentials

I have been pen testing an android mobile application for security vulnerabilities.
As part of the test, I started Frida server on a mobile phone where the mobile application to be tested is installed, running, and after login (Already inserted credentials and logged in).
While being logged in the application, I dumped the application's memory using Frida (with strings), and was able to find my session token in clear-text JSON format.

I was wondering, is there any way to mitigate this vulnerability? Of course it makes sense that the session token is saved in memory, but is there a way to store it securely (E.g. not in clear text) and thus mitigate such a vulnerability?

I find this issue risky as if the mobile device is rooted, a malicious mobile application (running with sufficient permissions) can conduct the same attack locally on the mobile phone and thus extract the session token.

Comment: The mitigation is to not root the phone and break the security barriers between memory locations.

Comment: Yet this is not something that can be decided by the application owner, if the mobile phone is rooted and the application is installed on it

Comment: So, you are asking how to mitigate this as an application developer? Not as the device owner? If so, please edit your question to include that.

Comment: If you encrypt this data and place it in memory, you are going to have to decrypt it in memory at some point.

Comment: Depending on the requirements/design, you might be able to use keystore to have key material outside of the app memory.

Comment: @domen OP is talking about a session token. I'm not sure how a keystore could help with that.

Comment: @forest it's also implied that's their solution, which means it could be redesigned. I can't find a popular implementation of challenge/response for web sessions though, so maybe it's not viable.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot mitigate this vulnerability without a major change in hardware. If your adversary has the ability to dump memory from arbitrary processes, there is no way to store credentials confidentially. On Intel's x86 CPUs, a feature called SGX can be used to create a secure enclave that can hide data even from the kernel, but that is not a feature that you have access to on typical Android hardware.

There are only a few places where data can be stored by a process. Typically, the data can be stored in memory (e.g. on the stack or in the heap), or in process registers. A rooted device running a malicious process with sufficient permissions will be able to access *all* of those locations. There is no way you can hide a session token. The reason is simple: The data needs to be retrievable by your process. Any data that your process can access, a malicious process with sufficient permissions can also access.

**The only solution is to not allow any malicious processes to have high privileges.**

Comment: Hello forest and thanks a lot for your thorough answer. Actually on PC's (x86's..) there are ways to mitigate this issue, for example, in Java you will create a list of char[]'s and then when you are done with using the password, you overwrite the list. Additionally as one suggested above in a comment, is it possible to use the Keystore for this? In order to store the password/session token encrypted in memory?

Comment: @user3091216 That technique wouldn't be sufficient as an attacker could pause the program and run it step by step. Whether or not a keystore works depends more on your exact requirements.